# How to use mappings_path in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

There is no detailed documentation about `mapping_path` in elasticsearch docs. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html

Can someone give an example of the file and the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> A path, either absolute or relative to the config directory, to a
>   UTF-8 encoded text mappings file containing a key => value mapping per
>   line.

So, the example of this file could be:

```
I => 1
II => 2
III => 3
```

and path obviously something like `/tmp/mapping.file` in Linux/Unix syntax or something similar in Windows syntax.